# If i must download image.png and image@2x.png where upload it from server?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, download, retina-display

I have some question.

When i create interface, i have image two resolutions (retina and non retina). 
I pointing "image.png" and it revert it to "image@2x.png" (in retina display. if retina image exist).

But when i download file and save in some directory (ex. "NSLibraryDirectory") on phone.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString *docFile = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.imageName]];
```

I get full file path (ex. "library/image.png")

Question is Xcode find image "library/image@2x.png" and substitute it in retina display.

Or save only images with largest resolution. And use its.

Comment: You set the image in Interface Builder, our you make it from code (like: imageView.image = yourimage) ?

Comment: Set from code ex. UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is No!, you should check if the current device is Retina, if so add "@2x" string to the path manually. @2x and normal images are converted to tiff while build phase of the xcode project and the executable finds for the resources automatically (@2x or normal). However, if you are keeping those images in file path of the device, you should manually check them for @2x.